# MongoDB Java driver 3.x: How to save java.sql.Timestamp?

Tags: java, mongodb

I've followed the tutorial [Getting Started with the 3.0 Java Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-3.0-java-driver/).

But when I save a doc with a java.sql.Timestamp value, there's error about codec. I know that from driver 3.x, there's something about codec, but I don't know how to use them to solve this problem.

I'm used to 2.x driver, but new to 3.x driver.

Comment: You need a codec to serialize types that aren't provided with BSON serialization methods. Start with [the codec docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/) for a simple example.

Comment: Have you solved? Thanks, i see this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1741.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of codes registry this way:

```
@Test
public void testTimestamp() {
    Map<BsonType, Class<?>> replacements = new HashMap<BsonType, Class<?>>();
    replacements.put(BsonType.DATE_TIME, Timestamp.class);
    BsonTypeClassMap bsonTypeClassMap = new BsonTypeClassMap(replacements);
    DocumentCodecProvider documentCodecProvider =
            new DocumentCodecProvider(bsonTypeClassMap);
    CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(
                    new TimestampCodec()),
            CodecRegistries.fromProviders(documentCodecProvider),
            MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());
    Builder optionsBuilder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
    optionsBuilder.codecRegistry(codecRegistry);
    MongoClientOptions options = optionsBuilder.build();
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(), options);
    MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("mydb");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test");
    try {
        collection.insertOne(new Document("date", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime())));
        assertEquals(Timestamp.class, collection.find().first().get("date").getClass());
    } finally {
        collection.drop();
        mongo.close();
    }
}
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33436425/2119009